# Any script document browser addin for SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, add-in, ssms

I am often making changes to some large sql script files containing hundreds of stored procs, and navigating through those is not an easy task. Is there an (free or cheap) addin for Management Studio that would allow me to easily navigate between statements in a script? Something like a list of CREATE TABLE/CREATE PROC statements, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Enlight worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I use at work [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with the [Function List](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Function%20List/FunctionList%20Plugin%20v2.1/FunctionList_2_1_UNI_dll.zip/download) plugin for editing SQL and works fine (although it has an occasional crash since the plugin is a beta version). I use it regularly with the script of a whole database and helps a lot when looking for a particular definition.

The default configuration for SQL only lists functions and procedures, but since the plugin rules (regex) are configurable I adapted it a bit for the SQL Server syntax and added more rules, so it shows by category tables, views, functions, procedures, indexes, etc..

PS: If you are willing to try it, I could share the XML file that stores the regex rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Summarize Script feature in the upcoming SQL Prompt 5 to navigate a large script.

As this isn't yet released, you can use the EA version in the meantime. For more information, visit http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=11846

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any add-ons for SSMS, but you could always create a database project in Visual Studios (database projects aren't included with BIDS i believe) to manage all of your scripts for your databases.

Comment: VS doesn't help navigate through SQL scripts